# How to copy/export SAS data output to specific cells in an existing Excel?

Tags: excel, automation, sas, export-to-excel, sas-macro

I have several output tables which I would like to export them into an existing Excel template file (weekly report).
So before this, I used to copy and paste manually into the specified cells on specified sheets, but since the number of SAS tables is more than 15, it is time-consuming to copy and paste all these 15 table sets one by one manually.
I feel like there must be some way to do the exporting automation. Your advice is highly appreciated.

The following is an ODS example that I used to export to a new excel file, but this time I would like to just export the dataset into an existing file (specific sheet and on specific cells).

```
ods excel file="/.....path...../monthly_report.xlsx" ;

proc print data=report1;
id no;
run;

ods excel close;
```

[sheet "gender", before this I copied the table from SAS output, and pasted on cell F3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewc2T.png)

[sheet "address", before this I copied the table from SAS output, and pasted on cell H3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seiHJ.png)

Comment: Please consider giving a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does your tables have the same name structure (prefix/suffix)? Does your table have the same structure (number of columns/rows)? Please have a look at [How can I send SAS datasets to specific cells ?](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-send-sas-dataresults-to-specific-cells-in-an-excel-spreadsheet/)

Comment: First, look into ODS Excel. Second, it's a pain to export to specific cells, so instead write your data to a rawData sheet and then link those cells to the ones that are formatted. This allows you more flexibility in your reports. Note that an Excel template works best where the number of row and columns in a table are fixed. Or expand only in one direction, preferably via rows not columns.

Comment: This is a really old way of doing what you want, but not recommended. I'd really try ODS Excel instead, possibly building everything in there. https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/en_ca/User%20Group%20Presentations/Edmonton-User-Group/FareezaKhurshed-CoordinateComplexReports-Spring2014.pdf